# convert a column into rows

Tags: python, dataset, dataframe

I used a webscraper and i got data only in one column like
A
B
C
1
2
3
4
5
6
I need the data in this form
A  B  C
1  2  3
4  5  6
Is there any way?

Comment: Not sure what type of data structure you have the data in, but if it is in a pandas dataframe or a numpy array you can use something like [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html): `numpy.reshape(data, (3, 3))` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the answer was already provided by Oxbowerce, if the data is in a form of numpy array, use this code:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

arr = arr.reshape([-1,3])
```

if the data is in a pandas DataFrame, the things get messy so I recommend you just converting it into the numpy array and reshaping it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'C', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

arr = np.array(df)
arr = arr.reshape([-1,3])
```